# How to add a "preview" stripe to my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to add a "preview" stripe to a site.
I like what blogger does when you click to preview editing a post (Anteprima means preview in italian)

[image]

Do you know how to make it as a layer in order to plug it without modifying the main html code of my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option to play with.   Just fiddle around with the values.  I used webkit rotation in this sample.  For more rotation compatibility, see [here](http://css3please.com/)

CSS:

```
.preview {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:-125px;
    width:400px;
    font-size:32px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#888; 
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin-x:50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y:0px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="preview">Preview</div>
```

Comment: This is nice, but it's not a browser wide solution.

Comment: @Robert See my note about rotation compatibility.  I simply didn't list the other options out.  It also seems to be what Blogger uses.

Answer (score 3):

You will either have to add an additional `DIV` or add an additional `SCRIPT` in document head. It's simpler with a DIV, because it will be there immediately without executing any script.

Example HTML (Version 1):

```
<body>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Example HTML (Version 2):

```
<body>
    <img class="preview" />
    ...
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.preview
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    /* omit all these if you use an IMG */
    width: 100px; /* adjust */
    height: 100px; /* adjust */
    background-image: url(...);  /* adjust */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution

Markup

```
<img src="preview-image.png" class="preview">
```

Css

```
.preview {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just insert a semi-transparent PNG with the content and position it at the top left corner couldn't you?